# In .net mvc, How jquery-validate plugin remote submit dynamic params

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

```
Roleid: {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 30,
    remote: {
        url: rooturl + '/Manage/Role/ExsitCheck',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: $("#Id").val(),
            rolename: $("#RoleName").val()

        },
        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
            if (data == "yes")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
},
```

If the rolename value was changed by some events,how could I validate my roleid with the rolename,my backend Framework was .NET MVC4.

Comment: You code need to be in the question, not a link to an image of it.

Comment: Why are you not just using the `[RemoteAttribute]` applied to you property (your script is then not required)?

Comment: Just read and follow the example in the docs:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 2):

Submit your dynamic parameters as per [the examples in the `remote` documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

Replace this...

```
data: {
    id: $("#Id").val(),
    rolename: $("#RoleName").val()
},
```

With this...

```
data: {
    id: function() {
        return $("#Id").val();
    },
    rolename: function() {
        return $("#RoleName").val();
    }
},
```

---

BTW, you also probably do not need `dataFilter`.  The plugin automatically takes care of the response from the server...

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for
>   valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid
>   elements, using the default error message. If the serverside response
>   is a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead",
>   this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of
>   the default.

In other words, if the server responds with `"false"`, then the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically consider this as a failed validation attempt on the field.

Comment: 5 years later and your answer is still correct even with ASP NET Core NET 5. Thanks a lot!